# Performance of defining functions inside a class vs. outside

Tags: c++, oop

I'm writing a program to play the board game Quoridor. I'm using minimax search, and a custom class to store the state. My question is : is there any performance difference in defining the functions A. inside the class, or B. outside the class, and pass a pointer.

My intuition (which might well be wrong) is that in case A, it will lead to some memory overhead, since each object of the class will have its own copy of all the functions. This will also slow down creating objects, since besides the data members, the functions also have to be created.

Another question I have is that for the default object returned by the constructor - is it faster to use the constructor or copy a pre-existing object?

Here's the code for the class:

```
class BGraph {
public:
    int rows;
    int columns;
    int walls;

    int row1;
    int column1;
    int walls1;

    int row2;
    int column2;
    int walls2;

    float time;

    // Stores whether a wall has been placed at a vertex.
    vector<int> wallsList;

    vector<set<int> > edges;

    void addEdge(int v1, int v2) {
        if (v1 > v2) {
            int t2 = v2;
            v2 = v1;
            v1 = t2;
        }
        edges[v1].insert(v2);
    }

    void removeEdge(int v1, int v2) {
        if (v1 > v2) {
            int t2 = v2;
            v2 = v1;
            v1 = t2;
        }
        edges[v1].erase(v2);
    }

    bool checkEdge(int v1, int v2) {
        if (v1 > v2) {
            int t2 = v2;
            v2 = v1;
            v1 = t2;
        }
        return edges[v1].find(v2) != edges[v1].end();
    }

    //Take row and column, return the vertex number.
    //For example, 1,1 -> 1, 2,1 -> row_length + 1
    int rc2v(int r, int c) {
        return columns * (r - 1) + c;
    }

    //Take vertex number, return (row,column)
    pair<int, int> v2rc(int v) {
        pair<int, int> ans;
        ans.first = v / columns + 1;
        ans.second = v % columns;
        if (ans.second == 0) {
            ans.second = columns;
        }
        return ans;
    }

    void addWall(Wall wall) {
        if (wall.horizontal) {
            removeEdge(rc2v(wall.row, wall.column - 1), rc2v(wall.row, wall.column));
            removeEdge(rc2v(wall.row - 1, wall.column - 1), rc2v(wall.row - 1, wall.column));
            wallsList[rc2v(wall.row, wall.column)] = 1;
        } else {
            removeEdge(rc2v(wall.row - 1, wall.column), rc2v(wall.row, wall.column));
            removeEdge(rc2v(wall.row - 1, wall.column - 1), rc2v(wall.row, wall.column - 1));
            wallsList[rc2v(wall.row, wall.column)] = 2;
        }
    }

    //There are two conditions - the edges that it is trying to break should EXIST.
    bool wallIsLegal(Wall wall) {
        if (wall.row <= rows && wall.row > 1 && wall.column <= columns && wall.column > 1) {
            if (wall.horizontal) {
                return checkEdge(rc2v(wall.row, wall.column - 1), rc2v(wall.row, wall.column))
                        & checkEdge(rc2v(wall.row - 1, wall.column - 1), rc2v(wall.row - 1, wall.column))
                        & wallsList[rc2v(wall.row, wall.column)];
            } else {
                return checkEdge(rc2v(wall.row - 1, wall.column), rc2v(wall.row, wall.column))
                        & checkEdge(rc2v(wall.row - 1, wall.column - 1), rc2v(wall.row, wall.column - 1))
                        & wallsList[rc2v(wall.row, wall.column)];
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Removes/adds edges to account for the presence of a player.
    void adjustForPlayer(int player){

        int i,j;
        if (player == 1) {
                i = row1;
                j = column1;
            } else {
                i = row2;
                j = column2;
            }

            bool e1 = (checkEdge(rc2v(i, j - 1), rc2v(i, j))); //h-x
            bool e2 = (checkEdge(rc2v(i, j), rc2v(i, j + 1))); //x-d
            bool e3 = (checkEdge(rc2v(i - 1, j), rc2v(i, j))); //b-x
            bool e4 = (checkEdge(rc2v(i, j), rc2v(i + 1, j))); //f-x

            if (e1 && e2) {
                removeEdge(rc2v(i, j - 1), rc2v(i, j));
                removeEdge(rc2v(i, j), rc2v(i, j + 1));
                addEdge(rc2v(i, j - 1), rc2v(i, j + 1));
            } else if (e1 && !e2) {
                removeEdge(rc2v(i, j - 1), rc2v(i, j));
                if (e3)
                    addEdge(rc2v(i, j - 1), rc2v(i - 1, j));
                if (e4)
                    addEdge(rc2v(i, j - 1), rc2v(i + 1, j));
            } else if (!e1 && e2) {
                removeEdge(rc2v(i, j), rc2v(i, j + 1));
                if (e3)
                    addEdge(rc2v(i - 1, j), rc2v(i, j + 1));
                if (e4)
                    addEdge(rc2v(i + 1, j), rc2v(i, j + 1));
            }

            if (e3 && e4) {
                removeEdge(rc2v(i - 1, j), rc2v(i, j));
                removeEdge(rc2v(i, j), rc2v(i + 1, j));
                addEdge(rc2v(i - 1, j), rc2v(i + 1, j));
            } else if (e3 && !e4) {
                removeEdge(rc2v(i - 1, j), rc2v(i, j));
                if (e1)
                    addEdge(rc2v(i - 1, j), rc2v(i, j - 1));
                if (e2)
                    addEdge(rc2v(i - 1, j), rc2v(i, j + 1));
            } else if (!e3 && e4) {
                removeEdge(rc2v(i, j), rc2v(i + 1, j));
                if (e1)
                    addEdge(rc2v(i + 1, j), rc2v(i, j - 1));
                if (e2)
                    addEdge(rc2v(i + 1, j), rc2v(i, j + 1));
            }
    }

    BGraph(int r, int c, int k, int t) {
        rows = r;
        columns = c;
        walls = k;
        time = t;

        row1 = r;
        column1 = c / 2 + 1;
        walls1 = k;
        row2 = 1;
        column2 = c / 2 + 1;
        walls2 = k;

        //r*c+1 so that we don't have to worry about the fact that these things are actually indexed from zero.
        wallsList = vector<int>(r*c+1, 0);

        for (int i = 1; i <= r * c + 1; i++) {
            set<int> s;
        }

        //Initialise horizontal edges.
        for (int i = 1; i <= r; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < c; j++) {
                addEdge(rc2v(i, j), rc2v(i, j + 1));
            }
        }

        //Initialise vertical edges.
        for (int j = 1; j <= c; j++) {
            for (int i = 1; i < r; i++) {
                addEdge(rc2v(i, j), rc2v(i + 1, j));
            }
        }
    }

    //Copy Constructor
    BGraph(const BGraph & obj){
        rows = obj.rows;
        columns = obj.columns;
        walls = obj.walls;

        row1 = obj.row1;
        column1 = obj.column1;
        walls1 = obj.walls1;

        row2 = obj.row2;
        column2 = obj.column2;
        walls2 = obj.walls2;

        time = obj.time;

        wallsList = obj.wallsList;
        edges = obj.edges;
    }

};
```

Comment: No, the member functions of a class are per class, not per object of that class. Almost without exceptions, the C++ way is that 'if you do not use it, you do not pay for it'. For example, member functions are not virtual by default in C++. This is one of the main reasons why C++ can be used for operating system kernels and very fast, resource-constrained hard real-time systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your two questions :

1) Is there any performance difference in defining the functions inside / outside the class ?

If you define the functions as non virtual, then you don't get any difference in terms of performance from defining the functions outside the class.

Every member non static function has an implicit parameter this , which preety much will lead to a prototype of a function with a pointer as parameter defined outside the class.

Code sample to exemplify :

```
  class A {
    void foo(){};
  }

  void outsideFoo(A* ptr);

  // A::foo() true signature is A::foo(A* this) 
  // which is identical to outsideFoo(A* ptr)
```

Non virtual functions are resolved at compile time, so you will have the same number of indirections.

If however the functions are to be made virtual, they will be slower then defining the functions outside the class because at runtime there will be a search inside the virtual functions table, then a jump to the function .

I would sugest for your case to use the functions as non virtual inside your class since it will bring code clarity.

2) Constructor vs Copy Constructor

In your case they're both as fast since you are making a deep copy .

The difference in performance from calling a Constructor vs a Copy Constructor is defined by implementation. If for example you have some refining to do to the data , for example generate a spatial division of the data or a sorting of the data , then a Copy Constructor would be faster since it will just copy the already generated spatial division / sorted data.

However if you just straightforward allocate / asign values in both of them, the performance will be the same.